# Trying to us Rotativa to generate a PDF from a Controller / View, but security restictions doesn't let Rotativa access the required controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, pdf, rotativa

So, I've got an Admin Controller that uses the `[Authorize]` notation with a single admin account (for content management purposes). If the administrator is not logged on, it redirects the user to the login view.

In the Admin controller, I've this ActionResult:

```
public ActionResult GeneratePDF(int? id) {
    return new ActionAsPdf("PrintOrder/" + id) {
        FileName = Server.MapPath("~/PDF/test.pdf")
    };
}
```

The above code is currently for testing purposes and will be modified later.

However, when I call the ActionResult from a `View` (beeing logged on as admin), it only generates a PDF of the Login View as if there is no valid admin session and the user gets redirected. The code works when using the `[AllowAnonymous]` notation on the PrintOrder `ActionResult`, but not when a valid user session is required.

Any ideas on how to let the `ActionAsPdf` method access the required PrintOrder method and still be secured by the `[Authorize]` notation?

I'm calling the Action from a View as follows:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("GeneratePDF", "Admin", new { id = item.ID })">Get PDF</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

After doing some lengthly research I've found another post with the same issue.

[Why does Rotativa always generate my login page? Why is it slow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35067191/why-does-rotativa-always-generate-my-login-page-why-is-it-slow)

The author suggests that the Rotativa code is placed in the same method that it needs access to as a solution. This seems to work as a workaround to the issue and is sufficient for now. However, while a more robust solution would be desired, this will have to do.